# Weird C Compiler, getting an error "ld: duplicate symbol _main"

Tags: c, xcode, macos, compiler-construction

I just started learning C, and wrote my hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I get a really long error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

 Ld /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug/CProj normal x86_64
        cd /Users/Solomon/Desktop/C/CProj
        setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
        /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CProj.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Products/Debug/CProj

    ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/helloworld.o and /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64
    Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I am running xCode

Should I reinstall DevTools?

Comment: Nope, I get the same exact error

Comment: What is the command line you are using to compile this code?  Chances are, your command line includes two .c files that both contain a `main` implementation.  Specifically, the error message seems to indicate that you are attempting to compile `helloworld.c` and `main.c` into one executable.

Comment: You are linking two different files that both declare main(). Look in the following to see if there are any files being linked that don't belong: /Users/Solomon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CProj-cwosspupvengheeaapmkrhxbxjvk/Build/Intermediates/CProj.build/Debug/CProj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CProj.LinkFileList

Comment: Yes, I suggest that you use the compiler in a terminal, `clang helloworld.c` works well

Comment: Wny was this question downvoted?

Comment: This is not a valid C program. You need `int main()`, not `main()`.

Comment: For the others help I have the same problem i was wrong at import, i have imported ".m" file rather the ".h". i just change it and it is working..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you *read* the error messages (specifically the line starting `ld: duplicate symbol _main in ...`), you'll notice that it's complaining about two `main` functions, one in:

```
......blah blah blah/helloworld.o
```

and the other in:

```
......yada yada yada/main.o
```

That means your project is screwed up somehow. Either you have two separate source files containing `main` or Xcode is supplying one automagically.

You just need to fix that.

Comment: great ans @paxdiablo, you save my time.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to interpret that message:

> Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

An error occurred

> Ld /Users/ …
>       cd …
>       setenv …
>       /Developer/…

This is the command that Xcode executed to perform the linking step. You can almost always ignore it and skip past the next blank line.

> ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/…/helloworld.o and /Users/…/main.o for architecture x86_64

This is the actual error message. It tells you that you have duplicate `_main` symbols, one in the file `helloworld.o` and one in `main.o`. This means you have to functions which are both called `main`, which isn't allowed. One of them is in `helloworld.c` and the other is in `main.c`. If you delete one of these functions or files, the error will go away.

> Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

This tells you the exit code of the command Xcode performed. It is less helpful than the error message, and I have never seen anything other than 1 for linking errors.

Answer (score 10):

I meet this problem as well. In "Target Membership", just tick the file you want to run. Untick this in other files you don't want to run. Then try again.

[image]

Comment: This works for me, after I uncheck all the targe files except the one associated to the main.c . Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I realized that the better solution was to remove all object (.o) files from the same folder. They cause the duplication and if you want to debug the other .c files you should not remove their membership.

Answer (score 3):

It is also important to remember that you could have received this error message if you had a `#include "...filename..."` that created a duplicate copy of your function calls. However, in your case, that is not likely.

remember that `#include` essentially just copies and pastes a copy of your code where the `#include` takes place.

Comment: Alex your answer helped me i have imported my viewController.m instead of viewController.h file